# FileNotFoundError when using os.rename, but not when calling up print function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Disclaimer, I'm extremely new to coding and python so catering responses for a beginner would be awesome. I'm basically trying to rename a directory by calling on specific values from a CSV file. I'm able to print the new name I want just fine. As soon as I add the os.rename(src, dst) function I get the error

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory...

And yes, I've triple checked the file paths for typos and mistakes.

I've successfully used this code in a simplified version w/out trying to rename from the csv.

```
import os, csv

os.chdir("/Users/.../test11")
root = "/Users/.../test11"

for file in os.listdir(): #delete ds_store files b/c they mess up index value
    if file.endswith(".DS_Store"):
        path = os.path.join(root, file)
        os.remove(path)

src = "/Users/.../test11/temp_name" # rename (date/name/index)
csvFilePath = "/Users/.../test11/temp_name/data.csv"
with open(csvFilePath) as csvFile:
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
    for csvRow in csvReader:
        timestamp = csvRow["Timestamp"]
        name = csvRow["First name"]
        for index, folder in enumerate(os.listdir(root), start=1):
            new_folder_name = f"{timestamp}_{name}_{index}"
os.rename(src, new_folder_name)
```

Any help would be much appreciated. If there's a way to make this code more efficient, correct bad practices, or if there's a better approach I'm open to suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

`src` never changes, but you `os.rename` it multiple times (once per loop). It might have existed the first call, but definitely not by the second.

Comment: That makes sense, but then if I have the os.rename outside of the for functions, it has the same error.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you currently have :

```
src = "/Users/.../test11/temp_name"
```

and

```
new_folder_name = f"{timestamp}_{name}_{index}"
```

I would say that you are missing the path "/Users/.../test11/"

maybe this would solve your issue?

```
new_folder_name = "/Users/.../test11/" + f"{timestamp}_{name}_{index}"


def create_path(x):
if not os.path.exists(x):
    os.makedirs(new_folder_name)

os.rename(src, new_folder_name)
```

Comment: type print(new_folder_name) and give me the output

Comment: Could  you also try removing your temp folder ?
shutil.rmtree( " temppath " )

Comment: print(new_folder_name) gives me "2019/09/12_John Smith_2" (the folder is the second one in the directory)

Comment: I don't want to remove the temp folder. It has important stuff in there.

Comment: "2019/09/12...." is just the f"{timestamp}_{name}_{index}", what about when you do this:
new_folder_name = "/Users/.../test11/" + f"{timestamp}_{name}_{index}"
print (new_folder_name)
Try copy+paste in the Windows Explorer and see if the path is correct....

Comment: when I print that , the path and file name are correct

Comment: Then maybe the problem is because you the folders "2019/09/12_John Smith_2" don't exist.... 
You would have to create it first with os.makedirs : 


def create_path(x):
 if not os.path.exists(x):
     os.makedirs(x)
create_path(new_folder_name ) 

I will edit above.... here looks ugly

Comment: same result. print function is exactly what I'm looking for, os.rename gives the exact same error when I ad that os.makedirs.

Comment: OP seems to have layers of directory in both src and dst, better print them out together to make sure.  
if there are multiple dst, print them multiple times before call rename multiple time